# Create/Modify a System View using PLUGIN OR JavaScript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to Create/Modify a System View using PLUGIN OR JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this sample about how to work with views

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594431.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328457.aspx